# Transactions not showing in Copay wallet until confirmed?

Tags: copay

when i sent btc to my copay wallet, the transaction would show up before being confirmed, but wouldnt let you spend it. seems that isnt true anymore, anyway to have this happen again? havent found anything in settings

Comment: Have you checked the transaction and receiving address in a blockchain explorer?